# will `return` be caught on error in a try/catch block?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `try/catch` block within which I run my synchronous function call, I wonder why it won't be caught by the `catch` if the function `return` an `Error`. In this case I have a known issue in `mySyncFunction` and I don't want to throw on that, because I want the `test` function to catch that

```js
function test() {
  try {
    return mySyncFunction();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('my error message', error);
    return [];
  }
}

function mySyncFunction() {
  try {
    // Do stuff
    const expectedIssue = true;
    if (expectedIssue) {
      return Error('the known issue happended');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw Error(e)
  }
}

console.log(test());
```

Comment: Did you simply try it?

Comment: I have rephrased my question @Bergi

Comment: Oh, now I see. You're **returning** an `Error`, not **throwing** it. That's why it isn't caught.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thanks , but my question still remains, why it is not caught by the catch

Comment: Because it's not thrown!

Comment: @PersianIronwood Ah, that's a completely different question, thanks! However, it's totally expected - only `throw`n *exceptions* are getting caught. Just creating a `new Error` (and doing whatever with it) is not an exception.

Comment: yes , sorry I phrased it wrongly before , I  rephrased my question.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no error occuring during the call of `this.mySyncFunction(args)` it will returns normally. However, if there is an exception raised during this call, it will simply go directly to the catch, `console.error` your error and return `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not **throwing** an `Error`, you're **returning** one. `Error`s and other exception are only caught when you throw them, not by simply being around.

The correct way to actually see the exception being caught is

```js
function test() {
  try {
    return mySyncFunction();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('my error message', error.message); // notice error.message
    return [];
  }
}

function mySyncFunction() {
  throw new Error('my error'); // notice throw
}

console.log(test());
```

Comment: thanks, in my case  I have a known issue in `mySyncFunc` that I don't want it to be caught there , and I want the `test` function to handle if that known issue occurs.

Comment: Then you should check for the type of the return value of `mySyncFunction` (like `if (returnedValue instanceof Error) { ... }`. But it's better to treat exceptions as such. Or return (both on success and failure) an object that contains both the result *and* the outcome (like `{result: 123, outcome: 'ok'}` or `{result: undefined, outcome: 'error'}`)